# Android library gradle: how to print out androidTest compile classpath for debugging

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

Android library gradle: how to print out androidTest compile classpath for debugging? e.g.,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'

    androidTestImplementation project(':foo');
}
```

Tried:

```
println configurations.androidTest.compileClasspath
println configurations.androidTestCompileClasspath
```

Error:

```
unknown property androidTest, androidTestCompileClasspath.
```

EDIT:

used --debug to see the compile classpath. but project "foo" jar (classes) is not in the test compile classpath. Why?

EDIT: added compiling command from --debug output

```
    11:27:43.282 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler] 
 Compiler arguments: -source 1.7 -target 1.7 
-d C:\android-lib-example\build\intermediates\classes\test\debug 
-encoding UTF-8 -bootclasspath E:\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar
-g -sourcepath  -proc:none -XDuseUnsharedTable=true -classpath


C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit\4.12\2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec\junit-4.12.jar;

C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\animated-vector-drawable-25.1.0.aar\f97492dd0e3fdadec6eb864c7c5f9c1b\jars\classes.jar;

C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-vector-drawable-25.1.0.aar\3c7296b328661991fdc71417c2d3bee1\jars\classes.jar;

C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-v4-25.1.0.aar\94e0a99978ef389c19875873a05b1f90\jars\classes.jar;

C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-fragment-25.1.0.aar\9aa33ddea262de0fccf596b63d77e126\jars\classes.jar;

C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-media-compat-25.1.0.aar\d4283a71d22582569e7b8f8b8555ea5f\jars\classes.jar;

C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-utils-25.1.0.aar\ecfa150f33947ae29fdf1ef9d2019a6f\jars\classes.jar;

C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-25.1.0.aar\5bc41bc6c62195438dccd9c10e096590\jars\classes.jar;

C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-25.1.0.aar\a4d11eed7378e9aafb89f99d6889c32a\jars\classes.jar;

E:\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-annotations\25.1.0\support-annotations-25.1.0.jar;

C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;

C:\android-lib-example\build\intermediates\classes\debug 

-s C:\android-lib-example\build\generated\source\apt\test\debug 

<test source list here>
```

Note that the command is one line, added line breaker only for easy reading.

The test compiling classpath does not have the project "foo". It should include foo.jar or its equivalent classes directory.

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to debug?

Comment: like to know what artifacts(jar or directory) of project "foo" are included in the test compile path? The project foo contains an annotation processor, it is not invoked.

Comment: Try finding the gradle options which print more output. I think it is -v or --debug or something like that.

Comment: used --debug to see the compile classpath. but project "foo" jar is not in the test compile classpath.

Comment: Can you show the important parts of the output? What are you expecting to see that is different than the actual output?

Comment: added the compiling command line from output. thanks.